# Is it possible to join a hive table with an in-memory table in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning Spark SQL, and got confused about Spark's SessionCatalog and Hive MetaStore.

I've learned that the HiveSessionStateBuilder will create a new Analyzer with HiveSessionCatalog.

Does that mean that we can join hive table and in-memory table in one spark sql?

```
/**
   * Create a [[HiveSessionCatalog]].
   */
  override protected lazy val catalog: HiveSessionCatalog = {
    val catalog = new HiveSessionCatalog(
      externalCatalog,
      session.sharedState.globalTempViewManager,
      new HiveMetastoreCatalog(session),
      functionRegistry,
      conf,
      SessionState.newHadoopConf(session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration, conf),
      sqlParser,
      resourceLoader)
    parentState.foreach(_.catalog.copyStateTo(catalog))
    catalog
  }

  /**
   * A logical query plan `Analyzer` with rules specific to Hive.
   */
  override protected def analyzer: Analyzer = new Analyzer(catalog, conf) {
    override val extendedResolutionRules: Seq[Rule[LogicalPlan]] =
      new ResolveHiveSerdeTable(session) +:
      new FindDataSourceTable(session) +:
      new ResolveSQLOnFile(session) +:
      customResolutionRules

    override val postHocResolutionRules: Seq[Rule[LogicalPlan]] =
      new DetermineTableStats(session) +:
      RelationConversions(conf, catalog) +:
      PreprocessTableCreation(session) +:
      PreprocessTableInsertion(conf) +:
      DataSourceAnalysis(conf) +:
      HiveAnalysis +:
      customPostHocResolutionRules

    override val extendedCheckRules: Seq[LogicalPlan => Unit] =
      PreWriteCheck +:
      customCheckRules
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Spark can join hive table and in-memory table. The common abstraction for both type of data source is DataFrame. So if you read an hive table as

```
val dfhive = spark.read.table("hivetable")
val df = spark.read.parquet("sqltable")
```

Here both df and dfhive both of type Dataframe so you can use Dataframe APIs or spark sql to join them.

Comment: Can I join them in a single sql?For example, I have a hive table A, and I register a temporary table B usging a DataFrame. Can I just join them like below  
val result = spark.sql("select * from A join B on A.id = B.id")

Comment: What I really want to know is, what's the relation between SparkSession's catalog and HiveExternalCatalog?

Comment: As far as my knowledge it should work. I have saved dataframe as a hive table and used that directly in the spark-shell.